# Having multiple "if" statements

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax

I'm trying to make a basic login program that asks the user for a username and password, and records any right or wrong text in a logfile. The problems I'm having are that when I try to have more than 1 username and password combination I get syntax errors.

```
#login program
output = open("logfile.txt", 'a')
login = input("please enter the correct username and password\n")
a = "username password"
b = "username1 password1"

if a in login:
    print("successfully logged in")
    import time
    localtime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
    output.write("Somebody successfully logged in at ")
    output.write(localtime)
    output.write("\n")
    output.close()
if b in login:
    print("successfully logged in")
    import time
    localtime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
    output.write("Somebody successfully logged in at ")
    output.write(localtime)
    output.write("\n")
    output.close()

else:
    print("access denied.")
    import time
    output = open("logfile.txt", "a")
    localtime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time())
    output.write("Somebody unsuccessfully logged at ")
    output.write(localtime)
    output.write("\n")
    output.close()
```

Error:

```
  File "test.py", line 28
    output.write("Somebody unsuccessfully logged at ")
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: *Where* do you get the syntax error?

Comment: "I get syntax errors." **WHAT ARE THE ERRORS????**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a missing parentheses.

Comment: Thus spake Harry: "this code is terrible and messy" and lo and behold, I saw the truth in those words.

Comment: I'm not certain that this question is necessarily on-topic, but I would say that my answer brings it back into scope, as it's now about how the interpreter itself behaves.  Answers to the questions unasked...

Answer (score 7):

You are missing a closing parenthesis in your `else:` block:

```
output = open("logfile.txt", "a")
localtime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time())
                                  #-----------------^
```

This causes Python to report a syntax error on the next line. All you need to do is add that one missing `)`; you have 3 opening parens, but only 2 closing.

Answer (score 2):

To add a bit more to Martijn's answer, the python interpreter strips newlines within parenthesis.  So, the python interpreter, rather than seeing

```
localtime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
output.write("Somebody unsuccessfully logged at ")
```

(correct parenthesis added), the interpreter actually sees

```
localtime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()) output.write("Somebody unsuccessfully logged at ")
```

where `output.write("Somebody unsuccessfully logged at ")` is another argument to time.asctime.  This will obviously throw an error about invalid syntax.  I hope that gives you a bit more understanding of what's going on, and why the error appears one line after where you would expect.